# Remove a message in login page

Tags: login

Under the login page of Wordpress, I have a message  saying:

> "Only registered and logged in users are allowed to view this site, please login".

The problem is that I am **not** running an English installation of WordPress, and that this message is displayed in English.

How can I remove this message or translate it? Under my element inspector, it is appearing like:

```
<p class="message">Only registered and logged in users are allowed to view this site. Please login now<br></p>
```

I dont know where the code responsible of generating this, also, if it is a core file, I am avoiding touching it.

**Question:** How can I use a code in `functions.php` to hide this message or translate it?

Comment: As I just did a cross file search, I can't confirm that this message exists. I as well did a cross file search for the HTML tag with that class and couldn't come up with anything from WP core that is related. Seems like it's a plugin message?

Comment: @Kaiser, I totally agree with you, I am using a plugin "Private only" which is responsible of displaying this message, I thought at the beginning it is core message. Thanks for this smart remark. I 'resolved' the problem using accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language) and then get the po an mo files your need to translate wordpress in your language. You can put these files `/wp-content/languages/`.

This should translate your login page too.

EDIT: if you're stuck with your issue you can hook some styles on login page and add some display none to the class message `.message{ display:none!important;}`

To do such a thing just write this :

```
 function custom_login() {
 echo ' <style>
    .message { display:none!important;}
  </style>';
 }
 add_action('login_head', 'custom_login');
```

Comment: I already have the po and mo files for that language, also I have wordpress running correcly in that language, front end and back end, except for the given message. Note that in login page I have other messages that are translated. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm editing this